# Logistic regression with categorial independent variabele

Tags: regression, logistic-regression, rstudio-server

I have two question regarding logistic regression.

1. I am doing a logistic regression on a binary dependent variabele and a independent variabele that consist of more than 100 categories. Is a logistic regression still the right choice? or is another test necessary?
2. I am using logistic regression solemly to find out if the dependent variabele has a relation with the independent variabele. Is it necessary in this case to split my data into training and test set. And what kind of test could I use to find out if the model I am working with is good.

Answer (score 0):

1. If the function allows it you can theoretically do it, however you better have a lot of data. Afterwards you can use an ANOVA to test whether the IV as a whole is significant.
2. No, train / test is used for prediction accuracy. You could use an ANOVA as above or a Chi-square test to check for goodness of fit.